# How to hide clr-dg-placeholder

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have a datagrid that always show the clr-dg-placeholder even if I did not ask for it.

Is there a way to avoid having it displayed? Right now, if my grid has only one line, I can see a second one that corresponds to the clr-dg-placeholder item.

Thanks

Comment: The line displayed is there to preserve the height of the datagrid with one row when / if the loading icon is displayed. Its an integrated part of the component for now. If you really want to remove it you could target the placeholder with css and hide it with `display: none`.

Comment: Hi @hippeelee, your trick worked for the line, but the space reserved is still there. Any other trick for me? :-)

Comment: It sounds like you will also have to adjust the min-height for one of the wrapper elements. Offhand, I forget which one but if you run into trouble feel free to post a stackblitz with what you are trying and I can take a look. (https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v012)